# How to put k8s multi container pod state to be ready when one of the container is terminated as it completed its task and terminated

Tags: kubernetes

A k8s pod having two containers. One of the containers has finished its job, so its state is as below:

```
Container1     
  State:          Terminated
  Reason:       Completed
  Ready:          False

Container 2 
    State:          Running
    Ready:          True
```

And this is what I expect. Container 1should come and exit once the job is done.
Container 2 should keep running alone.

But pod having container 1 and container 2 has its state as Not Ready which I want to change to Ready state so that it  can be reached by service

How can I bring this pod to Ready state

Comment: Can you explain your use case in more details? As mentioned in the answer seems like initcontainer will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes init containers will satisfy your requirement. Please take a look at [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

Comment: But container1 is dependent on container2. Once container 2 starts running, then container1 will run, complete its job and exit. But container2 will keep running

Comment: Init container doesn't depend on the application container. It just runs, completes the job and will be exited.